# Minimizing expected value using a multivariate normal distribution Matlab

Tags: matlab, distribution, minimization

I am trying to minimise the expected value of this function w.r.t the variable `Q` :

where `f(D)` is the probability density function of a multivariate normal distribution, `c0` and `cu` parameters.

This is what I have done so far :

```
syms X1
syms X2
syms X3

c0 = 1 ;
cu = 1 ;

x = [X1; X2; X3] ;
mu = [3; 5; 7 ] ;
sigma = [4,3,6;3,8,5;6,5,10] ;

s = mvnpdf(x,mu,sigma)

syms Q
syms D

f = (Q-D).*s ;
z = c0.*int(f,D,0,Q) ;
anon_z = matlabFunction(z) ;
g = (D-Q).*s ;
t = cu.*int(g,D,Q,inf) ;
anon_t = matlabFunction(t) ;
tot = @(Q) anon_z(Q) + anon_t(Q) ;

[x fx] = fminsearch(tot,0)
```

It gives me this error :

> Error in
>   symengine>@(Q,X1,X2,X3)Q.^2.*exp(conj(X1).*conj(X3).*(3.0./2.0)).*exp(conj(X2).*conj(X3).*(1.0./1.1e1)).*exp(conj(X1).*-3.0).*exp(conj(X2).*(3.0./1.1e1)).*exp(conj(X3).*(2.6e1./1.1e1)).*exp(conj(X1).^2.*(-5.0./4.0)).*exp(conj(X2).^2.*(-1.0./1.1e1)).*exp(conj(X3).^2.*(-2.3e1./4.4e1)).*exp(-8.75688228083863).*(1.0./2.0)
>
> Error in @(Q)anon_z(Q)+anon_t(Q)
>
> Error in fminsearch (line 189) fv(:,1) = funfcn(x,varargin{:});
>
> Error in multi_3giocatori (line 19) [x fx] = fminsearch(tot,0)

Can you help me fix this?

Comment: Do you really need to use symbolic math?

Comment: Not really, I just need to find the Q that minimises "tot", and of course the value that correspond to it.

Comment: Then don't use it. You should also provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you want to get some help here. There are too many things in your code that are not defined.